# Eclipse IDE: Cannot save custom component with a select list; works fine with Dev Console

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

Using Eclipse and the force.com IDE, I cannot save the following custom component to the server.  Eclipse gives the code a red box at the very top with the message of **Save error: null**

```
<apex:component >

<apex:attribute name="mediaPlan" description="Media Plan Diaplay custom object" type="MediaPlanDisplay" required="true"/>
<apex:attribute name="rfp" description="Apttus RFP object" type="Apttus_Proposal__Proposal__c" required="true"/>

       <apex:selectList value="{!mediaPlan.selectedReports}" multiselect="true"> 
           <apex:selectOptions value="{!mediaPlan.reportOptions}" />
       </apex:selectList>

</apex:component>
```

The above page saves perfectly fine using the browser-based page editor.

If I save the page in the browser and pull the change into Eclipse, there are no errors.  However, if I edit the page and make a trivial change like adding a space, I get the above error again.

Has anyone else found a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: I had faced a similar issue in the past and it turned out that the eclipse workspace had got corrupted. I created a new workspace and pulled the project into it and everything worked as normal after that.

Comment: I created a new workspace, pulled down the Sandbox code and edited the custom component.  I still get the same error.  I'm using Eclipse Kepler.